# Topological spaces X and Y and a continuous bijection $f : X → Y$ while $f^{-1} : Y → X $ is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Give an example of topological spaces X and Y and a continuous bijection $f : X → Y$ such that $f^{-1} : Y → X $ is not continuous.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then such a continuous bijection is always a homeomorphism, so you need an example where $X$ is not compact or where $Y$ is not Hausdorff. See my answer to this, different, question for examples of both: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698876/is-the-intersection-empty/698880#698880

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Any function $f : X \to Y$ with $X$ discrete is continuous. Find an example where $X$ and $Y$ have the same underlying set, $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

A really small example: Take a 2-point set and consider two topologies on it, namely the discrete topology and the trivial one. ("Trivial" means the empty set and the whole space are the only open sets it's also called "indiscrete".)  The identity function is continuous from the discrete to the trivial space, but not in the other direction.

Incidentally, there are two other topologies on a $2$-element set, and you might want to check which pairs make the identity function continuous, in which direction(s).

Answer (score 1):

$$
f : [0,1)\to \Bbb \{z\in \Bbb C:  |z|=1\}
\\
f(t) = \exp 2i\pi t
$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=[0,2\pi)$ and $Y=S^1$. Then $f:[0,2\pi)\to S^1$ defined by $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ is an example of such a map.